# C# NullReferenceException in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Monster1 : MonoBehaviour {

    private GameObject monster_;
    // Use this for initialization

    public Monster1(){
        monster_ = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Monster1"));
        float height = Random.Range(0, Screen.height);
        Vector2 monster1position = new Vector2(Screen.width, height);
        monster1position = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(monster1position);
        monster_.transform.position = monster1position;
    }
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
```

When I am trying to instantiate an object of that class there is a `NullReferenceException`.

```
void Start () {
        Monster1 monster1 = new Monster1();

    }
```

Any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: at ` Monster1 monster1 = new Monster1();`

Comment: Where is the camera object being instantiated?

Comment: @Daniel that was the error, I changed it to `Camera.main`. Thank you.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have resource named "Monster1"?

Answer (score 3):

2 things: You should never use constructors in your MonoBehaviours. Use Awake instead. So replace

```
public Monster1(){
```

with

```
public void Awake(){
```

Second, you never instantiate a MonoBehaviour with "new". You need to add it to a game object:

```
GameObject myGameObject = ...
myGameObject.AddComponemt<Momster1>();
```

Comment: thanx for the tips. I tried to do that and I am getting `Cannot implicity convert..."

Comment: Could you print the line that contains the error you are getting? I have a feeling you are instantiating a GameObject where you want to instantiate a Monster1